# Comment exprimer « limiting upper bound » en mécanique ?

Tags: science

Comment exprimer :

> limiting upper bound

en évitant la répétition de deux mots de même famille (limite, limitant) ?

Autrement dit, est-il possible de l'exprimer autrement ainsi :

> limite supérieure limitant

Le contexte est celui de la mécanique, pas des mathématiques. Le extrait complet suit :

> In a uniaxial stress state the material is assumed to be rigid up to a value of stress σ = σ0. At σ0, the material flows. Because of this limiting upper bound for the stress, it is to be kept in mind that all plasticity experiments (including thought experiments) are done with displacement control.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Il semble que le contexte soit *en gros similaire* au contexte mathématique d'un ensemble infini avec ses **majorants** (*upper bounds*) et son **plus petit majorant**  ou **borne supérieure** (*least upper bound*) où ce plus petit des majorants n'appartient pas aux éléments de l'ensemble dont les éléments satisfont à la condition de rigidité (mais cette dernière considération n'a pas d'intérêt ici). Le terme « bound » n'apparait pas en anglais dans les expressions « upper bound » et « lower bound » avant la première partie du XXe (1900-1930), et cela, on peut de ce fait le supposer, en tant que terme mathématique. La définition collective de ces expressions est « limiting value » (supérieure (upper)/inférieure (lower)); en supposant sans trop de risque que le physicien qui écrit « limiting upper bound » fait cela avec à l'esprit sa connaissance de l'analyse il doit considérer « upper bound » comme signifiant « majorant » et le qualificatif ajouté « limiting » n'est qu'une transposition du « least » qui vient de l'analyse. La signification est alors simplement « borne supérieure »; comme évidemment la borne ne peut être que supérieure dans le présent contexte « supérieur » est inutile et on peut traduire comme ci-dessous;

> à cause de cette borne sur la contrainte…

Il y a peu de possibilités que le physicien ait eu une autre idée en tête que l'idée mathématique générale de « une infinité de valeurs supérieures trop grandes »; le fait de remplacer « least » par «limiting » se comprend au vu de la rigueur que le premier terme implique et qui n'a pas exactement sa place en physique (sauf dans la mathématique pour la physique).

Answer (score 1):

Dans le contexte exprimé en commentaire de la question, je traduirais *bound* par *borne* et *limiting* par *contraignant*:

> ...à cause de cette borne supérieure contraignante...
>
> ...à cause de la contrainte imposée par cette borne supérieure...

Comment: Je suis pas fan de ton utilisation de *contrainte / contraignante* dans ce cas précis où... il s'agit de *upper bound for the **stress***. Alors... une contrainte contrainte... une contrainte imposée à une contrainte... certes, on peut comprendre mais je crains que l'ambivalence de ce mot n'en fasse pas un candidat de premier choix ici.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks (in no particular order) jlliagre, LPH, mouviciel, StéphaneGimenez, aCOSwt. All the answers and comments that I got were very helpful. Here is my attempt to interprete the original text and the particular structure in question.

> Dans un état de contrainte uniaxiale, le matériau est supposé rigide
>   jusqu'à une valeur de contrainte σ = σ0. Sur σ0, le matériau s'écoule.
>   En raison de **cette borne supérieure limitante de la contrainte**, il
>   faut garder à l'esprit que toutes les expériences de plasticité (y
>   compris les expériences de pensée) sont réalisées avec un contrôle de
>   déplacement.

Below the original text:

> In a uniaxial stress state the material is assumed to be rigid up to a value of stress σ = σ0. At σ0, the material flows. Because of **this limiting upper bound for the stress**, it is to be kept in mind that all plasticity experiments (including thought experiments) are done with displacement control.

Comment: *Sur σ0, le matériel écoule* n'a pas de sens. Matériau != matériel. D'où: *À  σ0,  le matériau perd sa rigidité* ou *le matériau rompt* ou peut-être *le matériau s'écoule*. Aussi: *En raison de la limite (supérieure) de contrainte que l'on peut imposer, il faut...*.

Comment: Il me semble que *limitant la contrainte* est plus naturel que *limitante pour la contrainte*.

Comment: *Sur σ0, le matériau s'écoule.*  → ***Au delà** de σ0, le matériau **se fluidifie** / **fond?**  .*

Comment: @jlliagre The text text refers to rigid perfectly plastic materials, i.e. materials without hardening. In this idealized case (real materials always have some hardening). σ0 is a bound that you cannot exceed. The displacement can go to infinity and the stress remains the same. https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/metal-forming-3/rigid_plastic.php

Comment: *Au niveau de contrainte σ0, le matériau perd ses caractéristiques* or maybe *se fracture*.

Answer (score -1):

« Bound value » : Ce genre de chose, dans ce contexte s'appelle un **seuil**. Par conséquent, l'*upper bound* c'est... : le **seuil haut**!

Et que fait un seuil haut ? Il **maximise** (ou *maximalise* ou encore *majore* c'est comme tu veux).

D'où : « Because of this limiting upper bound for the stress » pouvant être rendu par :

> (À cause / en raison) de cette (majoration / maximisation) de la contrainte par le seuil haut...

ou encore :

> Le seuil haut maximisant la contrainte...